# iOS Table cell styling

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In my iOS - swift project I need my table cells to look like this. I can get the multi select option by making the table editable. What I need to know is what are the ways that I can design a cell to look like this? How can I add that colored border at the bottom and how can seperate the cells to look like this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I can get the check boxes using editable options and the text by using subtitle view. But no idea how to get the borders and seperate the cells like that. Tried searching for different table cell styles in google. No much luck. That's why I wanted to get others ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The cells you show in your question are custom cells. To make that, you would need to design those cells yourself with views, labels, buttons, etc. There is no default/boilerplate code that can do this for you; you will need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You must create and implement this custom `cell`.

Create a New file, Cocoa Touch class, on next page select "subclass of: `UITableViewCell`" and name "CustomCell"

Create a New file, select User Interface (under iOS) and select Storyboard, and Name something like "MyCustomCell".  On this new storyboard drag a `Table View Cell`. Select this cell, and in identity inspector make the class = to the name of your "CustomCell" cocoa touch class file. Then go to Attributes Inspector and fill in "identifier" with "cell"

NOW

In your `TableViewController` file

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomCell

    // Here's where you set your CustomCell properties like label title, images, backgrounds

    return cell;
}
```

I don't know yet how to make the cells separated, but as to the border at the bottom just go to your "MyCustomCell" xib and add a view at bottom and change its background.

Maybe to get the space in-between  you can use some sort of Layer (CAlayer).